# Documentation for smart contract deployment on testnet & mainnet

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, testnet, mainnet

Can somebody point out where I can get the doc for smart contract deployment on testnet & mainnet? I am testing on plutus playground now and would deploy on testnet to try. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The present status is to use the method described in the Lobster challenge. https://github.com/input-output-hk/lobster-challenge. Please see the associated Youtube video too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find an example here, from `Alonzo-tesnet` repo (that repo includes another interesting exercises).

That was part of the Exercise 4.
[Exercise4-solution](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/main/Alonzo-solutions/exercise4/Exercise4-solution.md)